# Improving flow in Apache NiFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to simplify flow in Apache NiFi.

What I want:

1. Call Facebook Graph API to receive `campaigns` for ad accounts and save it to DB.
   Response example:

```
[ {
  "start_date" : "2018-10-15",
  "stop_date" : "2019-03-31",
  "id" : "608962192",
  "account_id" : "1007311",
  "name" : "Axe_Instagram_aug-dec2018_col",
  "status" : "ACTIVE",
  "start_time" : "2018-10-15",
  "stop_time" : "2019-03-31"
}, {
  "start_date" : "2018-10-08",
  "stop_date" : "2018-10-31",
  "id" : "61084542",
  "account_id" : "10240051",
  "name" : "Axe_IG_aug-dec2018",
  "status" : "ACTIVE",
  "start_time" : "2018-10-08",
  "stop_time" : "2018-10-31"
} ]
```

2. Call Facebook Graph API to receive `ads` for ad accounts and save it to DB.
   Response example:

```
[
   {
      "id":"23845",
      "account_id":"251977841",
      "name":"Post_2",
      "status":"ACTIVE",
      "campaign_id":"2384345125",
      "adset_id":"238125",
      "bid_amount":87,
      "updated_time":"2019-06-20T14:21:06+0300"
   },
   {
      "id":"23843453786320125",
      "account_id":"2251971478158841",
      "name":"Post_1",
      "status":"ACTIVE",
      "campaign_id":"238225",
      "adset_id":"2384325",
      "bid_amount":87,
      "updated_time":"2019-06-20T14:21:06+0300"
   }
]
```

3. Filter `ads`:

   - I should leave only active campaigns (from `campaigns`) using these rules: `stop_date` should be empty (NULL) OR `stop_date` should be > '2021-01-01'
   - Check if `campaign_id` from `ads` contains in result set above.

My current behaviour is:

- Completed 2 steps above; all data stored in DB.
- For each flow file from `ads` API I'm using next flow:
- `SplitJson` to separate `ad` one by one;
- `EvaluateJsonPath` to store `campaign_id` to attributes;
- `ExecuteSQL` with next statement for each flow file:

```
select *
from facebook_api.campaigns c 
where c.id = '${campaign.id}'
and (c.stop_date is null or c.stop_date > '2021-01-01')
```

This will return nothing or `active` (with my criteria) campaign. After that I can filter them with `RouteOnAttribute`: `${executesql.rows.count:lt(1)}`.

**But there is a problem.** Splitting source 300 flowfile creates about 100,000 flowfiles and I'll make a 100,000 unnecessary requests to db.

Can I perform requests with same logic without splitting flow files?

Answer (score 1):

Doing the SplitJson is really inefficient and probably not needed here.

You could do this with [PartitionRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.13.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PartitionRecord/index.html) to create FFs that are grouped by the `campaign_id` (and also have this as an attribute). This means that you do not need `SplitJSON` or the `EvaluateJsonPath` processors. Now you only end up with as many FlowFiles as there are unique `campaign_id`s in the original FF.

***Edit: I read this part wrong and assumed you were using QueryRecord - updated**

Now your original `ExecuteSQL` will still work, but has far fewer FFs to execute on.

*However*, I'd question why you need to hit an intermediary DB in the first place. Why not have NiFi filter the raw results from hitting the Facebook API?

You could replace the `ExecuteSQL` with a `QueryRecord` that does:

```
select *
from FLOWFILE where (stop_date is null or stop_date > '2021-01-01')
```

Passing only the matching records to an 'ACTIVE' relationship. This removes the need for the DB in the middle.

The resulting flow would look something like:

`InvokeHTTP` (hit facebook API) -> `PartitionRecord` (split FFs by campaign ID) -> `QueryRecord` (drop all inactive campaigns)

Another thing to consider...I don't know the Facebook Graph API very well - but are there no query parameters that you could add so that the filtering is done on the FB side?

Comment: I didnt find a tool to do it on FB side. Status `ACTIVE` is kinda stupid and doesn't really show the real activity. It can be empty `ad` without any actions, but with status `active` because this `ad` wasn't closed. So best way to filter `active` ads is sort them by `stop_date`. I will try `PartitionRecord` + `QueryRecord` as u suggested and will compare results.

Comment: `PartitionRecord` is not for this case. I'm using `ad_id` to send requests, but each `ad_id` is mapped with `campaign_id`. I need to check activity of `campaign_id` and then send requests using `ad_id`. `stop_date` doesnt exists in flowfiles, only in DB, so I can't use `QueryRecord`. And with `PartitionRecord` im grouping by `campaign_id` and after `ExecuteSQL` im losing all `ad_id` except one, because OneToMany (1 campaign id and many ad_id).